# Inserting untrusted data into EXCEL from CSV

Tags: excel, csv, security

I am exporting a un-trusted user-supplied data into CSV from my program.

Many modern spreadsheet programs such as Microsoft Excel and LibreOffice are able to interpret cell-level syntax consisting of an equal sign followed by a function name or an expression.

when user is opening this CSV in Microsoft Excel program, it executes. Kindly help how to generate the CSV using untrusted data which will not execute in Microsoft Excel.

what I have tried..
I have included a single quote in front of the untrusted data, but normal data is also getting that single quote and looks ugly.

Comment: What is untrusted? What is the danger of executing the formulas? 
CSV fields can be enclosed in double quotes. If the value itself contains ", then escape with "" Lile "x", "y", "Z""" if it helps

Comment: An attacker may inject functions or expressions that alter an affected spreadsheet’s content in an attempt to trick a victim into believing that the modified spreadsheet content is genuine.@dgorti

Comment: Then don't trust the source. 
Even if it does not contain formulas, the other data may be untrusted.

Comment: Can you give a couple of actual examples of exactly what you're trying to protect against?  I can't think of any example where including a formula in the data would really be different from substituting the formula result.

Comment: -2+3+cmd|' /C calc'!A0         Depending upon the system user privileges, an attacker can perform various tasks using the same.
If the user is with high privilege, it is easy to change the system password as mentioned below
-2+3+cmd|' /C net user administrator lol@123'!A0

Comment: Yes this is annoying. But there is a warning "Remote data not accessible.To access this data Excel needs to start another application...." with default Excel settings and the default is [No] and if somebody runs Excel logged in as a Administrator then this one should know what this message means.